# 80s(?) animated scifi/fantasy movie with spaceships, a fantasy castle, and a princess wrapped up in a carpet by bad guys

Tags: story-identification, movie, animation

I had this film on VHS as a child but can for the life of me not remember its name. I know it was a scifi/fantasy film.

There was a princess who had to be rescued frequently. In one scene she was wrapped up into a carpet by the bad guys.

There was some sort of fantasy castle and I think the whole movie played in space and there were spaceships. The hero had a sort of hero title, like "something-man" and I think the film was named after him, there might even be more than one film to this.

I'd guess it was produced in the 80s, but it could be older.

I'd wager the guess that it was animated in the US. It was very heroic and simple plot-wise. It had an anime-ish look to it, when it comes to character design, but I am pretty sure it wasn't an anime. I think it was rather crudely animated, with reused frames etc, which would make it something produced for TV/VHS. I was around 7 or 8 when I watched it, so my visual memory could be totally warped.

Comment: Could be 'He Man'?

Comment: What is a fantasy castle? How is it different from a real castle?

Answer (score 3):

Could this be "[Captain N: The Game Master](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_N:_The_Game_Master)"? It was cartoon series which ran from 1989 to 1991. "Captain N" is a kid from California who (along with his dog) gets sucked into Videoland through his television. He ends up in the Palace of Power (the castle) and teams up with video game heroes to fight video game villains. So there are both fantasy and sci-fi elements.

It did have a princess who occasionally needed saving. I think the carpet scene you refer to is from [episode one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z5N2dgN_Lac) (the scene starts around 8:25).